Alternative document for Carta de invitación?
I plan to apply for a Schengen visa for visit purposes (family). They've already made an appointment for me for applying with the invitation letter but the timing probably will be tight as they also need to send me the original letter.
So are there any other documents I can use for the same purpose? Does the receipt from the police plus the informal letter written by the host count?
I don't really wanna use the hotel booking method as I stay there for a month. One month in one hotel is "weird".
I am a Chinese citizen and resident in Ireland.

Which country do you live and which country are you a citizen?

Hi there from Ireland . I am the resident here.

Your nationality/citizenship is more important than where you are a resident (but that might make a difference as well.)

Chinese with long term visa here (stamp 4)

When are you planning to travel? Regarding hotels, there are lonh-stay hotel where staying one month is not weird at all, and you also have long-term accommodations on AirBnb and the like. But of course it would cost quite a bit, and if that's not your actual intention and/or that would be too high a cost for you, using that as justification would not be appropriate and could result in trouble for you. What is your relationship with the people visited? Parents? Siblings? Partner?

My uncle and he is Spanish.The problem is he didn't know is so difficult to have a cota for the police station In his area nowadays..I intend to travel on 30 Jan -1 feb this range . So I need to apply the visa before Jan 11 I assume.And he only able to book on Dec 18 which can be affected by the holiday season ..

We’ll see if someone else chimes in with a different opinion, but for now I only see two options: either you are prepared to pay for lodging (hotel, AirBnb…) for the duration of the stay (and the cost does not seem outrageous compared to your financial situation, though you could make the trip shorter), or you’ll have to wait for the carta de invitacion. Or you could invite your uncle to Ireland instead.

AFAIK you need the official notification approving the request for the Letter of invitation. See eg https://spainserviceimmigration.com/carta-de-invitacion/

Thx for the answer..yes I know the process. In fact he applied one for me 3 years ago. I still had the copy of the letter. Only problem is they move to new place so now they have to go to the local police station for apply which is so difficult compared to the old area. Guess I have to use the hotel way then

Note: do NOT say you are going to stay in a hotel if that is not your plan or if that seems very expensive compared to your ressources. That would be deception. Only state you are going to use a hotel if that is actually your plan and you can easily afford it.
